# Stopping nodejs process start by npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am in the process of creating some scripts to deploy my node.js based application, via continuous integration and I am having trouble seeing the right way to stop the node process.

I start the application via a `start-dev.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

scripts_dir=`dirname $0`
cd "${scripts_dir}/"..

npm start &
echo $! > app.pid
```

And then I was hoping to stop it via:

```
#!/bin/sh

scripts_dir=`dirname $0`
cd "${scripts_dir}/"..

echo killing pid `cat app.pid`
kill -9 `cat app.pid`
```

The issue I am finding is that `npm` is no longer running at this point, so the `pid` isn't useful to stop the process tree. The only workaround I can think of at this point is to skip `npm` completely for launch and simply call `node` directly?

Can anyone suggest an appropriate way to deal with this? Is foregoing `npm` for launching a good approach, in this context?

Comment: https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Forever](http://github.com/foreverjs/forever) can do the process management stuff for you.

```
forever start app.js
forever stop app.js
```

Try to avoid relying on `npm start` outside of development, it just adds an additional layer between you and node.

Answer (score 0):

just use supervisor example conf is like

```
[program:long_script]
command=/usr/bin/node SOURCE_FOLDER/EXECUTABLE_JAVASCRIPT_FILE.js 
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/long.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/long.out.log
```

where

SOURCE_FOLDER is the folder for your project

EXECUTABLE_JAVASCRIPT_FILE the file to be run

you can check the post [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps)

Comment: Is it possible to restart a supervisor job, via a non-root user. My applications are running as application specific users. We won't be allowing root access for deployments.